# Sprite long click in andengine

Tags: touch, sprite, andengine, event-listener, long-press

I am using an animated sprite and want to perform some action on its long click events, but it is not working.  Please help guys...

```
AnimatedSprite playBtn = new AnimatedSprite(MainActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH/2, MainActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT - 100, activity.tTextureRegion3, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager())               
{
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,  float X, float Y) 
    {               
        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
        {
            scoreInc = scoreInc + 10;
            score.setText("Score: " + scoreInc);
            width = width + 5;                  
            progressRectangle();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
};

this.registerTouchArea(playBtn);
this.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Long Press. I don't know how to use long press with a sprite...

Comment: On ActionDown check what time it is by `long time= System.currentTimeMillis();` . Then on ActionUp check if desired time passed by calculating difference in times. Second approach is to use onManagedUpdate to check if desired time passed from the start of your ActionDown event and then do what you need to do ;)

Comment: I have tried, but it is only working on pressing not on long press...TimerHandler t = new TimerHandler(0.025f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
      
       if (sceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
             {           
              //Do Some Stuff               
             }     
     }

Comment: Also look into this: http://www.matim-dev.com/catching-long-click.html

Comment: HI Lukasz, I want to use Long Touch Event on my Sprite (not on scene as per above code).

Comment: I would not use timehandler here. Try like this:
1. onActionDown should register curent time in `long startTime = System.currentTimeMills();`
2. onActionUp you should check `long endTime = System.currentTimeMills();`
3. then also in onActionUp you should have:
`if(endTime > startTime + 1000){ //or something else then 1000... your choice of time
//do your stuff
}`

Comment: @Lukasz, Thanks for the update. But I want to perform action (Update Score and increase/decrease strength, show animation) when player has kept sprite pressed, not after player has released as per your suggestion.

Comment: I have used TouchEven.ACTION_MOVE and its working...

Answer (score 0):

I have used this

```
@Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,  float X, float Y) 
        {                   
            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{   //Done my Work}
```

and it worked

Comment: OMG... IO understood that you want to perform some action after some time passed after the touch event, not during all time of the touch event...

Comment: Still Thanks Lukasz. I have learnt something from your comments that I would be able to use later :)